# retrieve email from CRM in the activities from account entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

This is my code for sending email.

```
private void SendEmail(Guid accountToGuid)
    {
        string name = GetName(service, accountToGuid);

        #region Email
        Entity fromParty = new Entity("activityparty");
        fromParty["partyid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", ownerId);
        Entity toParty = new Entity("activityparty");
        toParty["partyid"] = new EntityReference("account", accountToGuid);

        Entity Email = new Entity("email");
        Email.Attributes["from"] = new Entity[] { fromParty };
        Email.Attributes["to"] = new Entity[] { toParty };
        Email.Attributes["subject"] = "Hello " + name;
        Email.Attributes["description"] = "Your account has been confirmed by Admin";
        Email.Attributes["ownerid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", ownerId);
        Guid EmailId = service.Create(Email);

        SendEmailRequest req = new SendEmailRequest();

        req.EmailId = EmailId;
        req.IssueSend = true;
        req.TrackingToken = "";

        SendEmailResponse res = (SendEmailResponse)service.Execute(req);
        #endregion
    }
```

Lets say, I already sent an email to account. Email will display in activities section. How to retrieve it from `SDK`?

Comment: Which SDK? What have you tried?

Comment: crm sdk 2016.. i mean i create a website which direct connection to crm. any idea how to do it? or plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform either:

*(Full examples in links)*

[Retrieve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrieve.aspx) - When you already know the record Id, email Id in your case.

[RetrieveMultiple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrievemultiple.aspx) - When you don't know the record Id, but you are going to search based on some other criteria, e.g. emails related to the account Id.